# Codeigniter Ajax call not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

From one of my View i am using a function to make ajax call.The function is not working.In the console the error message shown is as follows:

```
POST http://localhost/jsnci/section/ajax_call_pop_district_data/10 404 (Not Found)

XHR finished loading:POST"http://localhost/jsnci/section/ajax_call_pop_district_data/10".
```

and i'm making ajax call as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popDistrictData(){
        var dist_id = document.getElementById("ddlDist").value;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url()?>section/ajax_call_pop_district_data/"+dist_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                if (res)
                {
                    jQuery("div#districtData").html(res.username);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

What i don't understand is in the console, why at first it shows 404 error then 
the same function executes??.Please help.

```
My controller code:
public function ajax_call_pop_district_data($did)
{
   $dist_data = $this->District_model->pop_district_data($did);
   echo $dist_data;
}
```

My model code:

```
public function pop_district_data($did)
{
    $html_dist_data='';

    $sql="SELECT d_name, d_about, d_attraction, d_howtoreach,d_img_nm
              FROM districts
              WHERE d_id= ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($did)); //<---Here passing parameter to sql query
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $html_dist_data.='<strong>ABOUT '.$row['d_name'].'</strong>';
            $html_dist_data.='<p>';
            $html_dist_data.='<a href="#" class="alignright"><img src="'.site_url().'assets/admin/uploads/district_img/'.$row['d_img_nm'].'" alt="Map of '.$row['d_name'].'" class="alignright" /></a>';
            $html_dist_data.= $row['d_about'];
            $html_dist_data.='</p>';
            if($row['d_attraction'] != ''){
                $html_dist_data.='<strong>ATTRACTIONS</strong>';
                $html_dist_data.= $row['d_attraction'];
            }
            if($row['d_howtoreach'] != ''){
                $html_dist_data.='<strong>HOW TO REACH ?</strong>';
                $html_dist_data.= $row['d_howtoreach'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $html_dist_data;
}
```

Comment: 404 is an HTTP error. It means resource you've requested is not found (or the server says so)

Comment: what is your controller code for ajax method?

Comment: But that particular function is there in the controller

Comment: you are using dataType: 'json' in you ajax call so replace your code in controller as echo json_encode($dist_data); and in success function  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res); jQuery("div#districtData").html(obj.username); and also put a forward slash before section/ajax_call_pop_district_data in url param and also return a complete result set in model function and compose your html string in ajax call's success function.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your Controller Code Like This

```
public function ajax_call_pop_district_data()
{
   $did = $this->uri->segment(3);   
   $dist_data = $this->District_model->pop_district_data($did);
   echo $dist_data;
}
```

Script Like This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popDistrictData(){
        var dist_id = document.getElementById("ddlDist").value;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url()?>index.php/section/ajax_call_pop_district_data/"+dist_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                if (res)
                {
                    jQuery("div#districtData").html(res.username);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```